# Prevent ReSharper removes the existing region while doing file formatting

Tags: resharper

I have a file layout that gonna apply when I reformat the code. It is doing well. However, I got some specific codes that I have a #region around them. The ReSharper would remove these existing #region and apply its pattern.

Is there any way to prevent that? I selected [Remove Regions] to None for the Pattern setting but it doesn't work.

[Screenshot of the File Layout Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmIKW.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure several things:

1. Set *Remove Regions* to *None* in the *Default Pattern*
   [image]
2. Enable *Apply file layout* in the code cleanup profile of your choice
   [image]
3. Check all other R# layers to make sure that your custom layout doesn't get overridden.

Doing all these checks, the region *MyRegion* doesn't get removed on code cleanup.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I did check the 1st and 2nd items. They are set up as what you show me in the picture, but it still removes #MyRegion. Regarding the 3rd one, I am not sure where to find R# layers...

Comment: See here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Sharing_Configuration_Options.html